# Refresh WooCommerce product page on added to cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WordPress and I am using WooCommerce for a online store. I have found a small issue on one of the plugins that i needed for a specific product, and now I shall need to refresh the page automatically after adding the product on cart.

How can I easily do it without compromise the whole store? Is there anyway I can achieve this?

I did try to search for the origin php or js for add to cart event, but I couldn't find anything, and afterwards I tried to add a `location.reload()` to the add to cart class but it didn't solve my problem as well. This is everything i've tried so far.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you.  It will refresh your page when the add to cart button is clicked. Add it to your functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'refresh_function');

function refresh_function(){
header("Refresh:0");
}
```

Comment: Hello John, thank you very much for your answer !

Can i use that code on a snippet or it is required to be applied on functions.php ?

Comment: I am not sure if it will work in a snippet, you could always try it.  But I know it works in the functons.php

Comment: Well i did try it on a Snippet and unfortunately it didnt work so i just should paste it on functions.php, anyway, where can i find that file (functions.php) ?

Comment: wp-content > themes > [YOUR THEME]  and the functions.php will be there.

Comment: Of if you're doing it from the wordpress side (I don't recommend it though in case you break something) its Appearance > theme editor  and the  functions.php will be on the right hand bar under "Theme Functions"

Comment: Hello ! Well i've tried to do that and it didn't work, could it possibly be from the product's plugin ? The product is a customized T-Shirt and for that i have a plugin to personalize the shirt, could it be from the plugin ? If it is, it actually doesn't make sense, since im forcing a page refresh, anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you think there is any possible way i can identify if that product id is open then when it clicks on to add cart it refreshes the page ?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are trying to solve? Btw my code did refresh the page, right? That didn't fix what you're trying to do? Also yes there's a way to run the code I gave only on a specific product ID.

Comment: Well, i think this will help : i have a personalized product plugin and i added a T-Shirt when i add the product to the cart there is a spinner on the designer Canvas that doesn't stop "spinning" i guess is a theme js error but i would like to refresh the page to ignore the error

Comment: And the code in my answer didn't solve that problem?

Comment: Nop, i tried on the functions.php in theme child and the active theme and nothing happened unfortunately which i think it is weird since it is kinda hard to dont work

Comment: I am dumb, im sorry, i actually just did to turn off not the WooCommerce AJAX Add To Cart but the Theme as one aswell so i turned off both and it did solve my problem

Comment: Ok great. Glad to have helped.

Comment: How do i close this ?

Comment: Click the check box next to my answer and select it as the best answer.